# Is there a way to add ACL per Blob (File) in an Azure Storage Blob Container?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm moving some files from S3 to Azure Storage. I was using ACL per file in the S3 Account, so I had some private files and some public files in the same Bucket.

The problem is that I cannot find a way to set ACL per file in Azure Storage, I see I can set ACL in the container, but no in the Blob.

Is there a way to do this, or is not possible in Azure Storage?

**Edit:**

I ended up using one container for public files and one container for private files, that made the transition from S3 to Azure Storage a little more difficult but I didn't want to add another layer of complexity to my app (Azure Data Lake).

Comment: Azure Data Lake STORAGE isn't really much more complicated than blob storage (but much more powerful and flexible), don't confuse it with Azure Data Lake in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Azure Data Lake Storage (ADLS) Gen 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-introduction) has built in support for [ACLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-access-control) at the files and directories level. ADLS Gen 2 is built on Blob Storage. You can easily manage the ACLs with many tools/languages such as [Storage Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-explorer), [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-powershell) or [Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-python).

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be what Im looking for, a question though, this seems to be specifically for analytics, is it ok if I use it just for file storage for my app?

Comment: You can use SAS (Shared Access Signature) to provide public access to the specific files on your container. You can even specify allowed IP ranges too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview

Comment: So you might want to consider again if file-level ACL is really what you need or you should leverage SAS.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that I cannot find a way to set ACL per file in Azure
>   Storage, I see I can set ACL in the container, but no in the Blob.
>
> Is there a way to do this, or is not possible in Azure Storage?

The answer to this question is no. You can't set the ACL at the blob container level only by setting it to any of the following values - `Private`, `Blob` or `Container (Full)`. All the blobs in that container will follow the same ACL.

Also, RBAC access is again applied at the blob container level and not at the blob level.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for.

We can set the ACLs at individual folder/files level in ADLS2. There is a manage access access option in storage explorer and you can set the permissions from there. This is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-access-control).